# Stripe - 'exp_month' parameter should be an integer (instead, is 02 ) in Django View

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, stripe-payments

I am in the beginning stages of building a checkout payment form using Stripe.  I am using the jquery.payment library for formatting my month and year https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment.

I created an `exp` input field to collect the data, but in order to get the Stripe required `exp_month` and `exp_year` fields I created them as new variables and took the value of my `exp` field and sliced the values I needed, then passed them to my view.

The correct values are being passed to my view but when it hits `stripe.Token.create` I get the `stripe.error.CardError: Request req_A16AvRkITlz3Oi: The 'exp_month' parameter should be an integer (instead, is 02 ).` error in console.  Side note: This form worked perfectly when I had a field specific for `exp_month` and `exp_year` but how much fun is that? :)

Below is my code for review:

**ajax**

```
var fields = {
    number: 'null',
    cvc: 'null',
    exp: 'null',
    exp_month: 'null',
    exp_year: 'null'
};

$('#plaqueFormBTN').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fields.number = $('#id_number').val();
    fields.exp = $('#id_exp').val();
    fields.cvc = $('#id_cvc').val();

    $('#loader').show();

    var exp_month = fields.exp.slice(0, 3);
    var exp_year = fields.exp.slice(5);
    console.log(exp_month);
    console.log(exp_year);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
            number: fields.number,
            exp: fields.exp,
            exp_month: exp_month,
            exp_year: exp_year,
            cvc: fields.cvc

        },
        url: $('#plaqueForm').attr('action'),
        cache: false,
        ...
```

**view**

```
def plaque_order_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PlaqueOrderForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            number = request.POST.get('number', '')
            cvc = request.POST.get('cvc', '')
            exp_month = request.POST.get('exp_month', '')
            exp_year = request.POST.get('exp_year', '')

            subject = 'New Plaque Order'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = [from_email]

            # Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
            # Get the payment token submitted by the form:

            token = stripe.Token.create(
                card={
                    'number': number,
                    'exp_month': exp_month,
                    'exp_year': exp_year,
                    'cvc': cvc
                },
            )
            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'02'` is a string so it needs to be converted to an int before getting passed to stripe. You might just need to do:

```
        exp_month = int(request.POST.get('exp_month', ''))
        exp_year = int(request.POST.get('exp_year', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be accessing the data via the `form.cleaned_data` dict rather than directly from the POST. Among other things, the form takes care of converting into the right data type.

Comment: Converting to an `int` worked as @danyamachine mentioned, but I agree with you about needing to use cleaned data, but I've always had issues getting it to work reliably.  I changed my fields to format like `exp_year = form.cleaned_data.get('exp_year')` and I got the error `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_A1C8GvSrpG3It3: Missing required param: exp_year.
`